# SpringBoot + Apache Shiro Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, shiro

I have problems with implement SprigBoot WebApp using Apache Shiro(I had same problems with Spring Security but I read that Shiro is easier to implement - Unfortunately for me Not).

So, at the beginning, I use springboot and shiro, my web pages are with *.html using thymeleaf and bootstrap, I use database MySQL using Hibernate and I don't want static users just from db, I'm trying to implements Shiro basing on a few tutorials but I can't do it.

What is my problem exactly? - I can't login. After clicking Login nothing happens, just "refres" page.

Bottom is full of my code:

**pom.xml Dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        <version>0.32</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**MainStConfig.java Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"app.controllers", "app.service"})
public class MainStConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = { 
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
            "classpath:/resources/", 
            "classpath:/static/", 
            "classpath:/public/", 
            "classpath:/webjars/"
    };
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }


    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {

        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setDispatchOptionsRequest(true);

        return servlet;
    }
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {

        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
        registration.addUrlMappings("/*");

        return registration;
    }
    @Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {

        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilter.setLoginUrl("/login.html");
        shiroFilter.setSuccessUrl("/index.html");
        shiroFilter.setUnauthorizedUrl("/index.html?error");


        Map<String, String> filterChain = new HashMap<>(); 
        filterChain.put("/", "anon");
        filterChain.put("/login", "authc,roles[guest]");
        filterChain.put("/admin/**", "authc,roles[ADMIN]");
        filterChain.put("/student/**", "authc,roles[STUDENT]");
        filterChain.put("/teacher/**", "roles,roles[TEACHER]");

        shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChain);
        shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager());


        Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();
        filters.put("anon", new AnonymousFilter());
        filters.put("authc", new FormAuthenticationFilter());
        filters.put("logout", new LogoutFilter());
        filters.put("roles", new RolesAuthorizationFilter());
        filters.put("user", new UserFilter());
        shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);

        return shiroFilter;
    }
    @Bean
    public org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager() {

        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(userRealm());

        return securityManager;
    }
    @Bean(name = "userRealm")
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public UserRealm userRealm() {
        return new UserRealm();
    }
    @Bean
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }
    }
```

**MainStApplication.java StartUp app**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainStApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainStApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**MainStInitializer.java**

```
public class MainStInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { MainStConfig.class };
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**UserRealm.java**

```
public class UserRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    @Autowired
    private UserManager userManager;

    public UserRealm() {
        setName("userRealm");
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordToken upat = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        User user = userManager.getByUsername(upat.getUsername());

        if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(new String(upat.getPassword()))) {
            return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user, user.getPassword(), getName());
        } else {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid username/password combination!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
        User user = (User)principals.getPrimaryPrincipal();

        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
        info.addRole(user.getType().toString());
        info.addStringPermission(user.getType().toString());

        return info;
    }
}
```

**LoginController**

```
@Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @ModelAttribute("userR")
        public User getUser() {
            return new User();
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String login() {
            return "login";
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String admin() {
            return "admin/index";
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/student/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String student() {
            return "student/index";
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/teacher/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String teacher() {
            return "teacher/index";
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String login(String username, String password) {
            Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
            if (StringUtils.hasText(username) && StringUtils.hasText(password)) {
                try {
                    currentUser.login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return "login";
                }
                return "redirect:index";
            } else {
                return "login";
            }
        }

        /*@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String login(Model model, @ModelAttribute("userR") User user, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
            model.addAttribute("login", user.getLogin());


            if(user.getLogin().equals("a")) {
                return "redirect:/admin/index";
            }
            if(user.getLogin().equals("s")) {
                return "redirect:/student/index";
            }
            if(user.getLogin().equals("t")) {
                return "redirect:/teacher/index";
            }       

            return "index";
        }*/
    }
```

**IndexController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping({"/", "/index"})
    String index() {
        return "index";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

**UserManager** this class using dao and User class from other project added to build path. For clarity - UserHash in future will be to hashing passwords, actually passwords in db are not hashed(hash_hash column in UserHash table), bottom example

```
@Controller
public class UserManager {
    private UserDao dao = new UserDao();


    public UserManager() {

    }

    public model.user.User getByUsername(String name) {
        model.entity.User u = this.dao.findByLogin(name);
        model.entity.UserHash h = this.dao.findPassByLogin(name);

        return new model.user.User(u).build(h);
    }

}
```

And screen of my db:
[Screen of 2 tables in DB: User and UserHash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmc7k.png)

Could someone help me to configure Shiro that I can correctly login using data from DB?

**UPDATE 1.**
And here is my login.html page

```
<body>
    <div id="bodyContainer">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="body">
            <div class="loginPanel panel-default center-block">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div>
                        <p th:if="${loginError}" class="error">Wrong user or password</p>

                        <form th:action="@{login}" th:object="${userR}" method="post">
                            <center><h1>Panel logowania</h1></center>
                            <div class="loginPanelInputFields">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">Login</span>
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{login}" id="username"
                                    name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="login..."
                                    aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" />
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="loginPanelInputFields">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">Haslo</span>
                                <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" id="password"
                                    name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="haslo..."
                                    aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" />
                            </div>
                            <br /> 
                            <br /> 
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info text-center center-block" value="Zaloguj" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

From my observations problem is in class MainStConfig exactly in this fragment of code for shiro chain:

```
Map<String, String> filterChain = new HashMap<>(); 
        filterChain.put("/", "anon");
        filterChain.put("/login", "authc,roles[guest]");
        filterChain.put("/admin/**", "authc,roles[ADMIN]");
        filterChain.put("/student/**", "authc,roles[STUDENT]");
        filterChain.put("/teacher/**", "roles,roles[TEACHER]");
```

What do I wrong? Always - no matter that I use correct or wrong data from db - Im redirecting again to login.html.
And in this situation using is method login() method = RequestMethod.GET NOT Post....

I have no errors. I just can't login, after write username, password and click Login my page refresh itself, in LoginController you can see unchecked method Login where I check something, for example if Username = "a" then redirect me to /admin/index.html - and this works perfect.

I checked something, when i'm going to /login.html and after trying to log executed is method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String login() {"
```

not

```
"@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
 public String login(Model model, @ModelAttribute("userR") User user, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
```

I can't understand why?

Comment: Can you please post an error you are actually getting? That would help us to figure out the problem actually.

Comment: I have no errors. I just can't login, after write username, password and click Login my page refresh itself, in LoginController you can see unchecked method Login where I check something, for example if Username = "a" then redirect me to /admin/index.html - and this works perfect. But in current method from tutorials is no action....

Comment: I checked something, when i'm going to /login.html and after trying to log executed is method "@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String login() {"
not "@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String login(Model model, @ModelAttribute("userR") User user, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {". I can't understand why?